# I need to sequence a Num_Linea column, but the sequence must be restarted for each ID_PO

Tags: sql-server, database-cursor

Currently the cursor does the sequence but does not restart when the `ID_PO` is different.

```
DECLARE @Num_Line as int;
DECLARE @CurNum_Line as int;

SELECT @Num_Line = 1;

DECLARE LINECURSOR CURSOR FOR
    SELECT Num_Linea
    FROM   #temp

OPEN LINECURSOR;

FETCH NEXT FROM LINECURSOR INTO @CurNum_Line

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
    UPDATE #temp
    SET Num_Linea = @Num_Line
    WHERE CURRENT OF LINECURSOR;

    SELECT @Num_Line = @Num_Line + 1;

    FETCH NEXT FROM LINECURSOR INTO @CurNum_Line
END;

CLOSE LINECURSOR;
DEALLOCATE LINECURSOR;
```

This is the result that I get

| ID_PO | Num_Line |
| --- | --- |
| 51249 | 1 |
| 51249 | 2 |
| 51249 | 3 |
| 51249 | 4 |
| 71086 | 5 |
| 71086 | 6 |
| 71086 | 7 |
| 71108 | 8 |
| 71108 | 9 |
| 71198 | 10 |

The result that I need:

| ID_PO | Num_Line |
| --- | --- |
| 51249 | 1 |
| 51249 | 2 |
| 51249 | 3 |
| 51249 | 4 |
| 71086 | 1 |
| 71086 | 2 |
| 71086 | 3 |
| 71108 | 1 |
| 71108 | 2 |
| 71198 | 1 |

Comment: it looks like a task for analytic-function ROW_NUMBER()OVER(PARTITION BY ID_PO). Could you please provide sample data and desired output

Comment: `ROW_NUMBER` is what you want. When writing SQL don't think programmatically, such thoughts will lead to slow results. SQL works in sets and so set based thinking is what you need to be using., Don't think what you need to do to the row, think what you need to do to the column.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I found the solution, it was as simple as this:

```
DECLARE @Num_Line as int;
DECLARE @CurNum_Line as int;
DECLARE @IDPO varchar(6);
DECLARE @LASTPO varchar(6);
select @Num_Line = 0;

DECLARE LINECURSOR CURSOR FOR
    SELECT Num_Linea, ID_PO
    FROM   #temp


OPEN LINECURSOR;

FETCH NEXT FROM LINECURSOR INTO @CurNum_Line, @IDPO
SELECT @LASTPO=@IDPO
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
    BEGIN
        
        IF(@LASTPO=@IDPO)
        BEGIN
                SELECT @LASTPO=@IDPO

            SELECT @Num_Line = @Num_Line + 1;

        END
        ELSE
        BEGIN
                SELECT @LASTPO=@IDPO

            SELECT @Num_Line = 1;
        END
        UPDATE #temp
        SET    Num_Linea = @Num_Line
        WHERE  CURRENT OF LINECURSOR;
      FETCH NEXT FROM LINECURSOR INTO @CurNum_Line, @IDPO

    END;

CLOSE LINECURSOR;

DEALLOCATE LINECURSOR;
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing built in for SQL Server to automatically have a resetting sequence and store the data the way you want. Instead, the current **recommended practice** is to store the data using a simple [`sequence`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-sequence-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) similar to the first (unwanted) result. Even worse, the data might now also develop gaps in the sequence.

However, there is still good news.

First, this lets you throw away ALL of your code: SQL Server will maintain this for you completely automatically, with no need to *EVER* run a manual update, and especially no need for a loop or cursor. You can probably get rid of the temp table, too. *(Pro Tip: the real professionals tend to avoid those constructs as much as possible).*

Second, this is enough information to display the data in exactly the way you want at output time. You accomplish this via the `row_number()` function and `PARTITION BY` clause. Assuming the data is stored in `#temp` using the first (bad) option, you can show it to the user the way you want by selecting from it like this:

```
SELECT ID_PO, 
    row_number() over (ORDER BY ID_PO, Num_Linea PARTITION BY ID_PO) as Num_Linea
FROM #temp
```

Comment: Isn't it a bit cleaner to just order by Num_linea?

Comment: @siggemannen Maybe, but for semantics if I partition by an item I like to ORDER BY it as well.